# When to assign services to 'this' in angular2 components or services?

Tags: angular, typescript, service, angular2-services

There are two ways that I see people using services in their components and or other services. A common use case is the `Http` service. Both cases import it:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

Case 1:

```
constructor ( private http: Http ) { 
   this.http = http; 
}
```

Case 2:

```
constructor ( private http: Http ) { }
```

Both cases result in the `Http` service being available at `this.http`.

Is there an advantage to using case 1 over case 2? Does it have to do with multiple instantiations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for `this.http = http` because

```
constructor ( private http: Http ) { }
```

transpiles to `this.http = http` and results in [doing this twice](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28private%20http%3A%20Http%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.http%20%3D%20http%3B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A).

It's either that, or

```
constructor (@Inject(Http) http) {
  this.http = http;
}
```

if the compatibility with ES.next and Babel is in priority.

Comment: Interesting... So it doesn't break anything, it's just redundant. It looks it's only useful doing `this.x = x` when we're not using the `private` keyword. [Example playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(http%3A%20Http)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.http%20%3D%20http%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D). Thanks!

Comment: That's correct. The syntax for visibility in constructors is there exactly to un-clutter the body of `constructor` function (most times it will be just `{ }` in A2 injectables).